# Blue gradient line on top and bottom instead of Ubuntu-USB-Grub-Screen

Tags: ubuntu, boot-loader, freeze, uefi

I just bought a E350M1 mainboard with onboard AMD Radeon 6310 Graphics Card.

I did (I think I did) the UEFI-Bios trick:

```
CSM activated
```

and plugged-in a usb-stick with an Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop i386 (made with [lili Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)).

Unfortunately I got a screen like this:

[image: freeze screen on mini-itx-board]

I cant see a menu, I am only able to reboot via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

I have no hd/cd/dvd/br/floppy only usb.

Any ideas?

Comment: My fault: the Lines on Top/Bottom seems to be part of the UEFI-Menu. Anyway, the system freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint 16 works.

Unfortunately I need to wait for release of other distributions.